# Is my Sub Collection is Also fetched when Fetching the Collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection "Ratings" inside this "Posts" collection so when i get any post will this collection will be fetched automatically or i have to reference it separately. And if this subcollection Ratings is fetched with the post so it'll be count as a separate read or same as the Post read?

```
final CollectionReference postsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts");
response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a collection will NOT get the subcollections. The subcollections need a separate read.... and reading collection or subcollection considered read.